# Different ways to construct python lists will affect the behavior of modifying the lists?

Tags: python, list, matrix

In Python 2.7.11, I am creating a two-dimensional list in this way:

```
array1 = [[0]*2]*2  
array2 = [[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)]
```

Both of them give me `[[0,0], [0,0]]`, but when it comes to modification, they yield different answers:

```
array1[0][0] = 1  
array2[0][0] = 1
```

Now `array1 = [[1,0], [1,0]]`, `array2 = [[1,0], [0,0]]`. Apparently array2 is what I expected, but any idea on why array1 behaves differently? I am assuming that array1 is copying the first row to create the matrix and therefore any modification to one of the rows will also affect other rows. But I have been using [None]*size to initialize a one dimensional list and it works fine all the time.

Comment: A good way to think about this is that `2 * some_list` is equivalent to `some_list + some_list`

Comment: Thank you@juanpa.arrivillaga for the answer and redirection to the other questions! It seems clear to me right now.